# "Object reference not set to the instance on an object" error in my C# unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to access the bone structure of my snake in unity2d and move the head by using this code. But it keeps throwing this error. I have applied Inverse Kinematics 2D CCD solver to rig the snake. I am hoping if I add velocity to the head the rest of the body will follow suite.

```
public class SnakeBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Head = transform.Find("bone_23");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Head.localPosition = new Vector2 (1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: transform finds your Head Right?

Comment: @Isparia Yes the bone rigged to my character which is the head

Comment: ok, so you problem is inside your Update Method, add a null check and act accordingly ^^